# adding a class to body in jquery fails in javascript methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below is my scenario

I have three **classes box** with randomly selected image and from **array items**, there is a square **box002** at right lower portion, this **can be drag and droppped to any of three box** `if it find match the box will dissappear`. likwise three box will dissappear.

then a **class bodyblue** is added to body with backgroundImage named `middle bg` is added to body for `10 seconds` . after again 3 box appear for drag and drop.

in the **second level** after this three boxes are dragged&dropped and deleted, when **bodyblue is added to body the backgroundImage middle bg is not appearing in for 10 seconds.**

**How to add bodyblue backgroundImage to body using jquery in second level and third level?**

```js
var array2 = [];
var arraycart = [];
var disparray = [];
var bg = [];
var dataURL;
var timeOut;
counter = 0;

var items = [{
 label: '1',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
  {label: '2',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'},
  {label: '3',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'},
  {label: '4',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'},
  {label: '5',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'},
  {label: '6',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'},
  {label: '7',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'},
  {label: '8',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'},
  {label: '9',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'},
  {label:'10',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10'}
];


var notes = ['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10'
];


var tempimages = [];
var notesselected = [];

array2 = items.slice();

var item;


//change backgroundImage


function changemainbackground() {

  bodycontents = document.getElementById('main');

  if (counter >= 0) {
    bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
    d = bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
  }
  counter++;
}
hiddenimgnumber = 0;

var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'];

//var bg=['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1','https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'];
var bg = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4'];

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];
}, 1)


function hiddenimage() {

  clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];

  //console.log(hiddenimgnumber);
  hiddenimgnumber++;
}
window.onload = function() {}

function rvalue() {
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    //debugger;
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #c57232 ";
    elements[i].style.borderBottom = "5px solid  #c57232 ";
    //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"

  }

  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  if (array2.length === 0) {
    alert('Game completed');
    return;

  }

  for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    try {
      //ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
      //ptags[index].textContent = "RS."+item.label;
      ptags[index].dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

      //using label as an identity
      tempimages.push({
        data: item,
        label: item.label
      });
      notesselected.push({
        data: item.url,
        label: item.label
      });

      boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';

    } catch (err) {
      // console.log('Exception');
    }
  }

  var tlen = tempimages.length;
}


function displayAllImages() {
  try {

    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();

    }

    if (tempimages.length === 0) {
      image = document.getElementById('slide');
      image.style.display = 'none';
      return;
    }

    var arr2 = tempimages;
    item = arr2[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr2.length)]

    image = document.getElementById('slide');
    //getting notes item
    //console.log(item);
    ///////console.log(item.label);
    var dataURL = notes.filter(a => a.indexOf("?text=" + item.label) > 0)[0];
    //var dataURL =item.url;
    //var dataURL = item.label;
    console.log(dataURL);
    image.src = dataURL;
    image.dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

  } catch (err) {
  }
};

$(function() {
  displayAllImages();
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");


  var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemLabel;
  var y = ev.target.dataset.itemLabel;

  if (ev.target.tagName === "DIV") {
    y = ev.target.children[0].dataset.itemLabel;
  }
  if (x == y) {
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    tempimages = tempimages.filter(a => a.label !== item.label);



    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();
      hiddenimage();
      animateCongrat();

    }
    displayAllImages();
  } else {

  }
}

//animate congarat starts here

var timeOut;
function animateCongrat() {
  $('.congrats').show();

  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  addBlueBody();
  hideCongratAndBlueBody();
}
function addBlueBody() {

  $("html").css("background-color", "  #070755  ");
  $('body').addClass('bodyblue')
  $('#container').hide();
  $('#2container').hide();
  $('#3container').hide();
  $('#2').hide();
  $('.completed').hide();
}

function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    $('.congrats').hide();
    $("html").css("background-color", "");
    $('body').removeClass('bodyblue')
    $('#container').show();
    $('#2container').show();
    $('#3container').show();
    $('#2').show();
    $('.completed').hide();
    changemainbackground();
  }, 10000);

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dashed {
  border: 2px dashed #999 !important;
}

.bodyblue {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x600?text=Middle+bg);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #99ffff;
  height: 16vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40.3vh;
  left: 50.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 15.0vw;
  height: 15.0vh;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 29.0vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 23.9vh;
  left: 19.2vw;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.reset img:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.hiddenimage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3vh;
  left: 50vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddenimage img {
  width: 10.3vw;
  height: 10.5vh;
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45.3vh;
  left: 17vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hand img {
  width: 25.3vw;
  height: 25.5vh;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="main">
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">


      <div id="container">

        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10" style="">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>

<div class="congrats">
  <div class="hiddenimage" style="display:none;">
    <img src="" id="hiddenimageid" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('main') return NULL

Comment: @mohit-agarwal how to correct this please explain a little more

Comment: "  var img = document.getElementById('main'),
    style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");"
can you explain what you're trying yo do here

Comment: @mohit-agarwal when running on local system i was trying to print backgroundImage filename from array.....but that doesnt matter i have used picsum photos for this snippet

Comment: your shared code is incomplete. I cannot drag anything plus just by looking at your code you declare 2 variables with the same value `var c = document.getElementById('main');


  var img = document.getElementById('main'),` and also, you have no element with id `main` and also you left a `debugger` in there

Comment: @mihai-t if you are accessing from pc just make run answer window fullscreeen.......there is a square box on right side of three boxes which can be dragged and dropped to any of three boxes

Comment: yes. i saw that box. and no, still not draggable, still no `main` id in the html, still a debugger and still 2 variables with the same value

Comment: @i agree there will no elemenet in that box and drag element(Dom) will not be visible during drag but , try droping on all three boxes any one will get deleted, likewise try next two

Comment: @mihai-t after 3 boxes get deletd a background image from class bluebody appears for 10seconds ...then after next three boxes load....in this level after three boxes get deleted , `the backgroundImage from class bluebody is not appearing for 10seconds` ...how to solve this?

Comment: @mihai-t please see the snippet now i have corrected what you told

Comment: you get this error `Cannot read property 'style' of null` . That's because you do NOT have an element with id `main` in your html

Comment: @mihai-t  i corrected the error now please check how can i achieve the bodyblue() to add to body on second loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you are not applying `bodyblue` class to `body`. `bodyblue` class is applied 2nd time also. But after 1st time, you set a background-image to body via javascript. Which is a more 'powerfull' style than with css. It has a higher priority so it overrides the styles from css in the 2nd attempt.

So you could use a more specific selector `body#main.bodyblue` in CSS or even `!important`.

See below

```js
var array2 = [];
var arraycart = [];
var disparray = [];
var bg = [];
var dataURL;
var timeOut;
counter = 0;

var items = [{
 label: '1',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
  {label: '2',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'},
  {label: '3',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'},
  {label: '4',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'},
  {label: '5',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'},
  {label: '6',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'},
  {label: '7',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'},
  {label: '8',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'},
  {label: '9',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'},
  {label:'10',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10'}
];


var notes = ['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10'
];


var tempimages = [];
var notesselected = [];

array2 = items.slice();

var item;


//change backgroundImage


function changemainbackground() {

  bodycontents = document.getElementById('main');

  if (counter >= 0) {
    bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
    d = bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
  }
  counter++;
}
hiddenimgnumber = 0;

var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'];

//var bg=['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1','https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'];
var bg = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4'];

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];
}, 1)


function hiddenimage() {

  clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];

  //console.log(hiddenimgnumber);
  hiddenimgnumber++;
}
window.onload = function() {}

function rvalue() {
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    //debugger;
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #c57232 ";
    elements[i].style.borderBottom = "5px solid  #c57232 ";
    //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"

  }

  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  if (array2.length === 0) {
    alert('Game completed');
    return;

  }

  for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    try {
      //ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
      //ptags[index].textContent = "RS."+item.label;
      ptags[index].dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

      //using label as an identity
      tempimages.push({
        data: item,
        label: item.label
      });
      notesselected.push({
        data: item.url,
        label: item.label
      });

      boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';

    } catch (err) {
      // console.log('Exception');
    }
  }

  var tlen = tempimages.length;
}


function displayAllImages() {
  try {

    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();

    }

    if (tempimages.length === 0) {
      image = document.getElementById('slide');
      image.style.display = 'none';
      return;
    }

    var arr2 = tempimages;
    item = arr2[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr2.length)]

    image = document.getElementById('slide');
    //getting notes item
    //console.log(item);
    ///////console.log(item.label);
    var dataURL = notes.filter(a => a.indexOf("?text=" + item.label) > 0)[0];
    //var dataURL =item.url;
    //var dataURL = item.label;
    //console.log(dataURL);
    image.src = dataURL;
    image.dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

  } catch (err) {
  }
};

$(function() {
  displayAllImages();
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");


  var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemLabel;
  var y = ev.target.dataset.itemLabel;

  if (ev.target.tagName === "DIV") {
    y = ev.target.children[0].dataset.itemLabel;
  }
  if (x == y) {
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    tempimages = tempimages.filter(a => a.label !== item.label);



    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();
      hiddenimage();
      animateCongrat();

    }
    displayAllImages();
  } else {

  }
}

//animate congarat starts here

var timeOut;
function animateCongrat() {
  $('.congrats').show();

  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  addBlueBody();
  hideCongratAndBlueBody();
}
function addBlueBody() {

  $("html").css("background-color", "  #070755  ");
  $('body').addClass('bodyblue')
  $('#container').hide();
  $('#2container').hide();
  $('#3container').hide();
  $('#2').hide();
  $('.completed').hide();
}

function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    $('.congrats').hide();
    $("html").css("background-color", "");
    $('body').removeClass('bodyblue')
    $('#container').show();
    $('#2container').show();
    $('#3container').show();
    $('#2').show();
    $('.completed').hide();
    changemainbackground();
  }, 10000);

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dashed {
  border: 2px dashed #999 !important;
}

body#main.bodyblue {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x600?text=Middle+bg)!important;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #99ffff;
  height: 16vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40.3vh;
  left: 50.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 15.0vw;
  height: 15.0vh;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 29.0vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 23.9vh;
  left: 19.2vw;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.reset img:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.hiddenimage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3vh;
  left: 50vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddenimage img {
  width: 10.3vw;
  height: 10.5vh;
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45.3vh;
  left: 17vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hand img {
  width: 25.3vw;
  height: 25.5vh;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="main">
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">


      <div id="container">

        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10" style="">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>

<div class="congrats">
  <div class="hiddenimage" style="display:none;">
    <img src="" id="hiddenimageid" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```